# How to resolve, Uncaught TypeError: videopath.addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am calling a function on button click, but facing the issue of Uncaught

> TypeError: videopath.addEventListener is not a function.

My HTML file.

I wanted to send the exact file path in my case which is a video path.

```
<div class="input-btn-container">
  <input class="input-box" id="videopath" type="file" />
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="renderbtn" onclick="runRender()">start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the function which I am calling here on calling this function getting error.

```
function runRender(){
  let client = "some functions";

  let videopath = document.getElementById('videopath').files[0].path;
  let result = document.querySelector('#result');

  // here I am getting error.
  videopath.addEventListener('input', () => {
    client.invoke("counter", videopath, (error, res) => {
      if(error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        result.textContent = res;
      }
    });
  });

  videopath.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There just needs a modification in the runRender() which should be like.

```
function runRender(){
  let client = "some functions";

  let videopath = document.getElementById('videopath');
  let vedioPathValue = vediopath.files[0].path;
  let result = document.querySelector('#result');

  // here I am getting error.
  videopath.addEventListener('input', () => {
    client.invoke("counter", vedioPathValue , (error, res) => {
      if(error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        result.textContent = res;
      }
    });
  });

  videopath.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

this is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an event to a non-dom element and therefore you get this error, try this.

```
function runRender(){
    let client = "some functions";

    let videopath = document.getElementById('videopath').files[0].path;
    let videopathElment = document.getElementById('videopath');
    let result = document.querySelector('#result');

    // here I am getting error.
    videopathElment.addEventListener('input', () => {
        client.invoke("counter", videopath, (error, res) => {
            if(error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                result.textContent = res;
            }
        });
    });
    videopathElment.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```js
function runRender() {
  let client = "some functions";

  let videopath = document.getElementById('videopath');
  let result = document.querySelector('#result');

  // here I am getting error.
  videopath.addEventListener('input', () => {
    client.invoke("counter", videopath.value, (error, res) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        result.textContent = res;
      }
    });
  });

  videopath.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

```html
<div class="input-btn-container">
  <input class="input-box" id="videopath" type="file" />
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="renderbtn" onclick="runRender()">start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```